# Nautilus launches minimized/maximized randomly

Tags: gnome, nautilus

My system: Ubuntu 15.04, GNOME Flashback (Compiz)
My problem: Nautilus usually launches ok (maximized, so I can start using it), but sometimes it launches minimized (just in bottom panel, so I have to click again to maximize it). Usually it launches ok when it's first program on bottom panel, but when there are some programs already minimized in bottom panel it randomly (still looking for some pattern) launches just minimized.

Not a big thing, but pretty annoying...

EDIT: I looked closely and found out that it's problem when I have previously opened Firefox browser (in that instance Nautilus opens (maximized) behind Firefox - I have to minimize Firefox or click Nautilus on bottom panel to get it).